# Error creating bean with name "*repository"

Tags: java, maven, jpa, repository, spring-data-jpa

I have a Maven project. `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>root</groupId>
    <artifactId>CourseWork5</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>coursework</name>
    <description></description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Also, I have an entity Address.

```
package root.entity;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Address")
public class Address {
   ...
}
```

I have repository for this entiry.

```
package root.repository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import root.entity.Address;

@Repository
public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, Integer> {
   ...
}
```

And service interface with implementation.

```
package root.service.interfaces;
import root.entity.Address;
public interface AddressServiceInterface {
    ...
}

package root.service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import root.entity.Address;
import root.repository.AddressRepository;
import root.service.interfaces.AddressServiceInterface;

@Service
public class AddressService implements AddressServiceInterface{
    ...
}
```

My application.properties file:

```
#DB properties:
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/labsdb?useSSL=false
db.username=root
db.password=rootPassword
 
#Hibernate Configuration:
db.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
db.hibernate.show_sql=true
db.entitymanager.packages.to.scan=root.entity
db.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create

spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/labsdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=rootPassword

security.require-ssl=false
```

My start file:

```
package root;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

But, after run the application I have errors:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name 'addressController': Unsatisfied
dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name 'addressService': Unsatisfied dependency
expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'addressRepository': Invocation of init method
failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:592)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:754)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]  at
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]   at
root.TestApp.main(TestApp.java:10) [classes/:na]    at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
~[na:1.8.0_65]  at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
~[na:1.8.0_65]  at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
~[na:1.8.0_65]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
~[na:1.8.0_65]  at
org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
[spring-boot-devtools-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE] Caused by:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name 'addressService': Unsatisfied dependency
expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'addressRepository': Invocation of init method
failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:592)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1131)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:589)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     ... 24 common frames
omitted Caused by:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'addressRepository': Invocation of init method
failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1131)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:589)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     ... 37 common frames
omitted Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:199)
~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]    at
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:266)
~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]    at
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:252)
~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]    at
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:84)
~[spring-data-jpa-1.3.3.jar:na]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     ... 47 common frames
omitted
```

Please, help me.
I have a simple app with the same structure and logic, but it works fine. So, I don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 7):

Add `@NoRepositoryBean` to your `CrudRepository`. This will allow auto-configuration to still occur without having to manually set the component scanning base packages.

The interface `org.springframework.data.repository.Repository` is a marker for an actual spring data repository. Since your `CrudRepository` extends `Repository` spring is trying to initialize a Spring managed repository named `crudRepository` for `T` (which essentially tranlates to Object). Since Object isn't managed by Hibernate it fails validation on startup and crashes.

`@NoRepositoryBean` will tell Spring to not generate a backing repository for a particular class that implements `Repository`.

Comment: For the future, wrap code in backticks `` so it's formatted as code. It makes questions and answer clearer and easier to read.

Comment: Thank you man, you saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have missed to

```
@Autowired 
Private AddressRepository addressRepository;
```

in your service method.

Answer (score -3):

The problem is that there is no implementation of AddressRepository.

I would recommend using stereotypes such as @Repository and @Service on the actual implementation rather than the interface.

*edit I now see that you're using spring data to provide the implementation of the AddressRepository interface. Maybe something is not wired up correctly there? The exception you posted indicates that AddressRepository could not be initialized. Having not used spring data before, I'm not sure why this is.*

Comment: @Repository is added on the interface !